# Stress distribution with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw a stress distribution with TikZ. It should looks like in the image below:

[image]

So far, I've just managed a triangular distribution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}             
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{center}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-0.2,0) -- ++(0,4);
    \foreach \i in {0.5,0.75,...,4} {
      \draw[-latex] (-2*\i/4-0.2,\i) -- (-0.2,\i);
    }
    \draw (-0.2,0) -- ++(-2,4);
  \end{tikzpicture} %
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I need help with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is good, the only minor challenge is to suppress the arrows in regions where they are too short. And using some `max` and `min` trickery allows you to draw the shapes on the right-hand side of your screen shot. Here are two examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}             
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{center}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,0) -- ++(0,4);
    \foreach \i in {0.25,0.5,...,4} {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Sign}{sign(int(4*(-0.8+2*\i/4)))}
      \ifnum\Sign=0
      \else
      \draw[latex-] (-2*\i/4-0.2,\i) -- (-1,\i);
      \fi
    }
    \draw (-0.2,0) -- ++(-2,4);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,4);
    \foreach \i in {0,0.25,...,4} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{min(max(-\i+2,-1),1)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Sign}{sign(int(4*\X)))}
      \ifnum\Sign=0
      \else
      \draw[latex-] (\X,\i) -- (0,\i);
      \fi
    }
    \draw (0,2) -- ++(-1,1) -- ++(0,1);
    \draw (0,2) -- ++(1,-1) -- ++(0,-1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture} %
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, I get following error: 
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `sign' (in 'sign(int(4*(-0.8+2*0.25/4)))'). }
Do I miss some libraries ?

Comment: @ingenium May it be that you have a very old version of Ti*k*Z? `sign` is part of the basic package, I believe, see section 89.3. Just type `texdoc pgfmanual` and see if you can find it there.

Answer (score 2):

This can be relatively easy using the `intersections` library. Only if an arrow is too short do we need this `\ifnum\i=` to cancel it. This method applies to all other shapes, I chose only the third one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}             
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw (0,0)--(0,5);
\draw[name path=line 1] (1,0)--(1,1)--(-1,3)--(-1,5);
\foreach [count=\i] \p in {0,.5,...,5}{
  \path [name path=line 2] (-3,\p)--(3,\p);
  \path [name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2}];
  \ifnum\i=5\else\draw[->] (0,\p)--(intersection-1);\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]